# Javascript pairwise comparison for difference between 6 variables

Tags: javascript, input, comparison, formula, getelementbyid

In javascript I am trying to automate the pairwise comparison of up to 6 integers in input boxes, comparing numbers as they are entered until 3 numbers are within 0.2 of one another. It is not necessary to enter all 6 values in order to have three numbers within 0.2 of one another, therefore some of the 6 potential input values may remain null or 0, but which should be ignored in the comparisons.

I have loaded the variables into a function i.e. var fev1 = document.getElementById('fevOne').value, but am not sure how to go about comparing each against one another apart from writing out every single possible case..

Does anyone have any idea how I should approach this?

My very sparse example code is below....

```
<head>
function reproduce() {
var fev1 = document.getElementById('fevOne').value;
var fev2 = document.getElementById('fevTwo').value;
var fev3 = document.getElementById('fevThree').value;
var fev4 = document.getElementById('fevFour').value;
var fev5 = document.getElementById('fevFive').value;
var fev6 = document.getElementById('fevSix').value;
//essentially, I don't know where to begin in building this formula, but imagine that I would need to use a loop
}

</head>
<body>
<input type="text" name="fevOne" id="fevOne" value="">
<input type="text" name="fevTwo" id="fevTwo" value="">
<input type="text" name="fevThree" id="fevThree" value="">
<input type="text" name="fevFour" id="fevFour" value="">
<input type="text" name="fevFive" id="fevFive" value="">
<input type="text" name="fevSix" id="fevSix" value="">
</body>
```

For a bit of background, I am building a medical form which will identify whether the lung function measurements (forced expiratory volume in 1 second, FEV1, measured in Litres) were collected with sufficient reproducibility (ie. 3 within 0.2L of one another), with the intent that the highest of these 3 values is taken as the clinically relevant value, stored for the patient.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Rory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general idea would be check all inputs anytime a change is made to one of them using a nested loop structure that compares all combinations of inputs. It has to be bullet proof for clinical use and allow technicians to change their minds and erase, alter and correct values. Note that if the spirometry tests have been completed and all results are entered, this example reports the maximum clinical fev identified, not the one that minimizes the difference between two test results.

Note the HTML of this example identifies each input using a zero based "data-index" attribute, not "id" property. The "fevSetup" function would normally be called after the window load event has fired while running the snippet calls it directly. The maximum difference was increased slightly because JavaScript 
decimal arithmetic is not always exact ( I haven't stored the text input by the technician which might be better for reporting purposes).

```js
function fevSetup() {

    var MAX_DIFF = 0.2000001;
    var values = [];
    var i,j;
    var fevInputs = document.querySelectorAll('[data-type=fev]');

    for( i = 0; i < fevInputs.length; ++i) {
      fevInputs[i].addEventListener("change", checkFev);
    }

    function checkFev() {
        var thisFev = Number( this.value);
        var index = Number(this.dataset.index);
        if(isNaN( thisFev) || thisFev <= 0) {
            console.log("Invalid input: " + this.value)
            this.value = "";
            thisFev = undefined;
        }
        values[ index] = thisFev // may erase a previous entry

        var clinicalFevs = [];
        for( var i = 0; i < values.length-1; ++i) {
            for( var j = i+1; j < values.length; ++j) {
                if( values[i] && values [j]
                 && (Math.abs( values[j] - values[i]) <= MAX_DIFF)) {
                  clinicalFevs.push( Math.max (values[i], values[j]));
                }
            }
        }
        if( clinicalFevs.length) {
            var clinicalFev = Math.max.apply(Math, clinicalFevs);
            console.log("Clinical Fev: %s", clinicalFev);
        }
    }
}   

// window.addEventListent("load", fevSetup);
fevSetup(); // for testing
```

```html
<input type="text" data-type="fev" data-index="0" value="">
<input type="text" data-type="fev" data-index="1" value="">
<input type="text" data-type="fev" data-index="2" value="">
<input type="text" data-type="fev" data-index="3" value="">
<input type="text" data-type="fev" data-index="4" value="">
<input type="text" data-type="fev" data-index="5" value="">
```

Naturally this code is supplied as is, without any form of guarantee or statement of fitness for purpose. I  hope, however, it provides you with something to go on.

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty: https://jsfiddle.net/8081wucv/2/

```
function check() {
  var text = document.getElementById('check');
```

Declare the function and get the element where I will put the bit of text

```
  var values = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {

  var value = document.getElementById('fev' + i).value;
    if (/\d+\.?\d*/.test(value)) {
      values.push(value);
    }
  }
```

Initialise the array and loop over the elements. If they're just digits with an optional point then push it onto the array

```
  values.sort();
  var passing = false;
```

Sort the array so we can do the next check easily and initialise the boolean that says whether or not the test passed.

```
  for (var x = 0; x < values.length; x++) {
    if (values[x + 2] - values[x] <= 0.2) {
      passing = true;
      break;
    }
  }
```

Loop over the array. If there are 3 elements (2 elements ahead, in the sorted array, minus this element) that have a difference of 0.2 or less then the test passes.

```
  if (passing) {
    text.innerHTML = 'passing';
  } else {
    text.innerHTML = 'not passing';
  }
}
```

Update the text.

You can remove the final block and change it to `return passing;` if you just want a function.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about this, but what about comparing Min and recurse ?

```
var inp = document.querySelectorAll('input'), // Jack's solution is more elegant. 
fevArray = [];

[].forEach.call(inp, (e) => {
  if (e.value) {
    fevArray.push(parseFloat(e.value,10));
  }
});

var recursiveCheck = function(arr){
  if (arr.length >= 3) {
    // If Max and min difference is not in the interval, change max with the second greatest value and recurse. 
    if ((Math.max.apply(null, arr) - Math.min.apply(null, arr) <= 0.2)) {
      return arr;
    }
    recursiveCheck(arr.splice(arr.indexOf(Math.max.apply(null, arr)),1));
  }
```

}

```
console.log("result", recursiveCheck(fevArray)); // should return undefined if not meeting conditions, or the array otherwise.
```